# Report Variable Values from Stored Procedure onto SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure with 3 nested loops which works perfectly in Query Analyzer.

I need to create an SSRS report to output the data from the stored procedure.
The stored procedure uses several variables to hold calculated data for the output as it loops through the code.

How do I pull those variables onto my SSRS report? When I add the variables as parameters, SSRS errors with "parameter is missing a value". The value is derived from the stored procedure. I have not found a way to make this connection.

Answer (score 1):

Its very annoying but you can only return one set of rows from a proc and for you to pass back anything it has to be in that table. So you will have to add columns to the passed back table which will contain the values you want on your report. I know this means that if you have a thousand rows these values will repeat 1 thousand times but that is the only way to return them.

Comment: Thanks for responding Benjamin.   Can you please explain what "one set of rows" means?    Does that mean only the first result from the loop will be reported?   Also, I'm sorry, but I don't understand what "the passed back table" is.  Is that the SSRS Dataset?   If it's the dataset, how do I add the variables to the dataset?    I have tried changing the Field Source in the Dataset Properties for each field in the table I'm reporting on to the variable name, but I get no results at all when I do that.

Comment: create a table in a SQL Server Proc with all the columns you will need. Then the columns you need for the paramater values you want to pass back. (Alter table1 add param1 int, param2 varchar(200)). Insert all the rows you need from your various selects. The last step is to update this table with the paramater values you need. (Update table1 set param1= saved value1, param2 = saved value2). Then the last thing you do in the proc select * from table1.